# iOS CoreData bulk/batch insert (sqlite TRANSACTION)

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 16000 records in *.txt* file and I want to insert all data in database using core data.
But operation performance is not good, taking very much time to read-insert data from *.txt* file to database (using CoreData).

In android, I am using [SQLite TRANSACTION](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) for achieving best performance and it's working fine.
But in iOS I'm unable to find a way.

**Note:** I have already tried the following post, but all provided reference URLs are showing **Error 404**: 
[iOS CoreData batch insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145888/ios-coredata-batch-insert)

Comment: Is it static data for all users?

Comment: @kirander: yes static data from file for all users. any idea how we achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to save using a completely separate stack (create a new persistent store coordinator and managed object context on private queue).  This is to take advantage of WAL - on by default in iOS7+.  This allows you to write without blocking your contexts that are reading.

You also want to import in batches, with each batch inside its own autorelease pool.  Save and reset the MOC.

I have ignored errors in this example, for clarity of an example that has nothing to do with dealing with errors... DO NOT do that...

```
- (void)importFromURL:(NSURL*)url batchSize:(NSUInteger)batchSize {
    // Open the URL so it can be used to read the text file

    // Create a new PSC, attached to the same store(s) as the PSC used by main context
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = // same MOM used by your main context
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:NULL];

    // A private-queue MOC
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
    moc.undoManager = nil;

    // Load all objects from the file, in batches
    NSUInteger total = 0;
    Record *record = nil;
    do {
        NSUInteger count = 0;
        @autoreleasepool {
            while (count < batchSize && (record = [self fetchNextRecord]) != nil) {
                [self createManagedObjectFromRecord:record inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                ++count;
            }
            [moc save:NULL]; // don't ignore the error
            [moc reset];
        }
        total += count;
    } while (record != nil);

    // Post a notification indicating that the import has finished.
    // This allows your main context to refetch from the store.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DidImport" object:self userInfo:@{ @"url":url, @"total":@(total)}];
```

Note that this assumes you have no relationships, and you are just loading straight objects.

If you do have relationships, you should load the objects first, then establish the relationships afterwards.

If your dataset is more like a bunch of small clusters of related objects, then you should load each small cluster as a batch, loading the objects, then connecting the relationships, then saving and moving to the next batch.

---

So, what does that example code do?

It creates a completely independent core data stack, which allows better concurrency during the import.

It loads objects in small batches.  This prevents memory allocations from getting out of hand, and keeps update sizes manageable.  This will help if you have the other context observing changes and automatically merging them in.  Small batches will have less impact on the other threads doing the merge.

Save after each batch commits the data to the store.  Reset the context frees any memory associated with the context, and allows the next batch to start fresh.  This helps limit memory growth.

The autorelease pool ensures that any auto-released objects are freed at the end of every batch, also helping reduce memory footprint.

The notification at the end allows you to notify other code to refetch from the actual core data database file.

For very large imports, this may be much more efficient than observing the saves of the context and merging each time.

This is obviously not working code, but it shows you how you should proceed.  If you follow this template, you should be able to import quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

As the data will be static you just need to preload all of it in a sqlite file by the Core Data. You can read about that [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data/).

Comment: Thanks, but i have also other 2-3 API's which getting data from server and each API's response contains 2000-2500 records. so how can i do bulk insert using core data?

Comment: There is also about it in the article. Read "Importing Data from Web Services" section.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily and efficiently following these tips:

- When importing, save in batches (e.g. every 500 records, experiment for best results)
- Use `@autoreleasepool`s to optimize memory
- Switch off the `undoManager` (set it to `nil`)
- Use a child context to do the insertions in the background. See the scheme below for the best setup for Core Data backup operations.

  rootContext (background)  - saves to persistent store
  mainContext (main thread) - use for UI
  workerContext (background) - do the heavy lifting (e.g. many inserts)

As you save the worker context, the UI is updated efficiently (it's all in memory) while the heavy lifting of data creation and saving to the physical database is done in the background.

This has performed excellently with 200.000+ records being inserted from a CSV file.

Note that doing all this in the simulator (even without the optimizations) and then putting the finished database sqlite file into the bundle as suggested elsewhere is also feasible and good practice.