# How to write a SwitUI wrapper for a legacy Table View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Looking for an example of how to write a SwiftUI wrapper for a table view.

The purpose of this is due to SwiftUI's limitations with regards to listing data. See [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383419/swiftui-coredata-fetch-is-very-slow), which describes what I believe is a current under-development and/or bug in SwiftUI wherein when using a large data set and modifying the number of rows displayed, the UI locks up and pins the CPU..

I believe at this time, the only work around would be to write a custom wrapper to incorporate a legacy table View into my SwiftUI View.. I can not figure out how to get this done, nor can I find any existing examples of this specific UIView. Can anyone offer any assistance with example code?

The table view would have to pull data from a CoreData entity..

I'd like to be able to call it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        MyCustomTableViewWrapper()

    }

}
```

This is what I have so far using UIViewRepresentable, what I can not figure out is how to get my CoreData into this UITableView:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct LegacyTableView : UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }


    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITableView {
        let control = UITableView()
        control.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        control.refreshControl?.addTarget(context.coordinator, action:
            #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl),
                                          for: .valueChanged)

        // Simply to give some content to see in the app
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30))
        label.text = "Table View Content"
        control.addSubview(label)

        return control
    }


    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITableView, context: Context) {
        // code to update scroll view from view state, if needed
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var control: LegacyTableView

        init(_ control: LegacyTableView) {
            self.control = control
        }

        @objc func handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
            // handle the refresh event

            sender.endRefreshing()
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIViewControllerRepresentable` or `UIViewRepresentable` as described in [Apple's tutrial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit).

Comment: Ref your answer, I have gotten part of this complete (see edited question above). Stuck in getting data into tableView..

Comment: I suggest you first make your regular `UIView` or `UIViewController` work in UIKit, without any SwiftUI code. When you have that working, wrap it in a Representable.

Comment: Found This source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html from Apple. Will get it working with that example. I’ll post my results when I get it. Thx for the idea, it nudged me in the right direction.